# Recoding data.table values in a loop using a vector of column names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data table that contains some categorical variables, where missing values have been coded as blank strings. I would like to recode them to NA.

I have a vector storing the names of the categorical variables:

```
categorical_variables = c("v3", etc.
```

The vector is definitely set up correctly - I have successfully used it to loop through plots of each column. However when I try to recode using this...

```
for (v in categorical_variables) myDataTable[get(v)=="",get(v):=NA]
```

...I get the following error:

```
 Error in get(v) : object 'v3' not found
```

Yet this works OK:

```
myDataTable[v3=="",v3:=NA]
```

And this also works OK:

```
myDataTable[get("v3")=="",get("v3")]
```

So it's when I try to do the assignment using get() combined with := it throws up the error. What am I doing wrong?

The data.table is very large (hence my preference for using data.table), so ideally I don't want to convert to data.frame and use a base R approach. I feel like this should be a very straightforward procedure in data.table, but I've really struggled to find anything conclusive in the documentation, on Google, or on here! Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Use `na.strings=""` in the `read.csv/read.table/fread` to read it as NA`

Comment: akrun's answer is great, but one other note: the problem with  `myDataTable[get(v)=="",get(v):=NA]` is that you want a column name on the left of `:=`. While `v` is a column name, `get(v)` is the column itself, a vector of values one for each row. Replace `get(v)` with `(v)`. One other thing: it's best to include an example in your question. akrun had to make his own for the answer because you didn't have one.

Comment: Hi @Frank , please could you post an example, as I don't think this works as you're suggesting? v is a string (e.g. "v3") and data.table normally needs an unquoted column name to the left of := which is where get() comes in. There are other situations in data.table and ggplot2 where this get(v) notation works perfectly well.

Comment: "data.table normally needs an unquoted column name to the left of :=" -- no, there are many ways to handle the left-hand side. "which is where get() comes in" -- no, `get` gets the values of the column. Example: `DT = data.table(v = c("a", "b")); DT[, get("v", DT) := 1:2]`. By the way, if your `get("v")` works without the `, DT` that means it is finding `v` in the global environment (perhaps because you used `attach(DT)` at some earlier point, which is dangerous since stuff like this can happen).

Comment: Further example, in case it's not clear how the parentheses work... `mynewvar = "d"; DT[, (mynewvar) := 4]`

Comment: Thank you Frank, very helpful. Am a bit surprised this question got downvoted - the documentation for data.table is quite light and I think this problem is quite instructive.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Kinda got to learn this stuff by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `set`.  According to `?set`, it is very fast as the overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided

```
library(data.table)
for (v in categorical_variables){
   set(myDataTable, i=which(myDataTable[[v]]==""), j=v, value=NA)
 }
```

However, this can be avoided while reading itself, as `fread` has the `na.strings` option (just like `read.csv/read.table`).  We can specify the characters that needs to be read as NA i.e. if we have `""` and `$` to read as `NA`,

```
myDataTable <- fread("yourfile.csv", na.strings=c("", "$"))
```

#### data

```
myDataTable <- data.table(v3=c(letters[1:3], ''), 
        v5 = 1:4, v7 = c('', '', letters[1:2]))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! You spotted my mistake when I loaded the data. The most practical solution to my problem is indeed to set na.strings="", as you suggest, but thank you also for offering a general answer to the question which will be useful for other purposes.